# Websocket 'unable to connect to the remote server' after random number of connections

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I've written a small Winforms application in C# to load test an AWS websockets API that triggers a Lambda function. The application makes *n* calls to the API, with a given period, each submitting a randomised payload in the request. Different payloads result in different runtimes for the Lambda function (between a fraction of a second and several minutes).

Calling the API involves the following steps:

1. Connect
2. Send a message containing credentials, the route action and
   the request payload (containing a small amount of data needed to
   fulfil the request)
3. Receive the result
4. Disconnect

These steps are carried out in a Task which is added to a `List<Task>`. These tasks are then run using `Task.WhenAll(taskList)`. Simplified (redacted) code is below. I'm completely prepared for people who know more than me to tell me it's terrible.

```
async Task RunTest()//Triggered by a button.
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
    {
        //Generate inputPayload string.

        taskList.Add(CallAPI(inputPayload, i, i * period));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
}


public async Task CallAPI(Dictionary<string, double> requestBody, int requestNumber, int delay)
{
    if (requestNumber > 0) await Task.Delay(delay);//No need to delay the first one (although 'delay' is 0 on the first one anyway).

    using (ClientWebSocket websocketClient = new ClientWebSocket())
    {
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        await websocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://..."), cancellationToken);//Exception is thrown at this line after a random number of tasks.

        InputStructure requestPayload = new InputStructure
        {
            Action = "RouteThatCallsLambda",
            Name = nameTextBox.Text,
            ApiKey = apiKeyTextBox.Text,
            ApiRequestBody = requestBody
        };


        while (websocketClient.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            byte[] messageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestPayload));
            await websocketClient.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messageBuffer), System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            break;
        }


        //All the 'record' bits do here is write stuff to a text box on the UI, and to a List<LogEntry> that I use to write out to a CSV file at the very end.
        ArraySegment<byte> buffer;
        System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
        MemoryStream memoryStream;
        while (websocketClient.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
            receiveResult = null;
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            do
            {
                receiveResult = await websocketClient.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, receiveResult.Count);
            }
            while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            if (receiveResult.MessageType == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string resultPayload = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                //If successful, the payload will contain "validData".
                if (resultPayload.Contains("validData"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Record the success.
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //Record the error (which in most cases would be a deserialisation exception).
                    }

                    await websocketClient.CloseAsync(System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else if (resultPayload.Contains("ping"))
                {
                    //Ignore - the Lambda function sends a message for long-running requests to keep the connection alive.
                }
                else //Failed.
                {
                    //Record the error message sent by the Lambda function.

                    await websocketClient.CloseAsync(System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            break;
        }


        if (websocketClient.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Closed)
        {
            //Record the connection closure.
        }

    }

    if (requestNumber == numberOfRequests - 1)
    {
        //Record process complete.
    }
}
```

The most I've ever set numberOfRequests to is 100 but it never gets that far before `websocketClient.ConnectAsync()` throws an 'unable to connect to the remote server' exception. In the CloudWatch API log stream, it reports 'Method completed with status: 410' which does suggest a client-side issue, but why it would strike at random I don't know.

Usually it gets to between 60 and 80 but sometimes after only a handful. Because it seems to be random, sometimes if I set numberOfRequests to much fewer it runs successfully all the way through. I've never seen any problems when I've set it to 1.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

### Update:

[I originally posted the following as an answer to my own question, but it appears that all it's done is make the exception rarer. I have no idea why that would be the case.]

It appears I've solved it. I saw on a couple of websites the following way of doing things but I didn't think it would make any difference. However, on the basis that I already had an inkling that the problem was due to some strange threading issue, I gave it a go anyway.

I moved the two `while (websocketClient.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)` blocks into their own separate async Tasks, one for sending the message and one for receiving the result. Then immediately after `websocketClient.ConnectAsync()` I await a call to each in turn, passing the necessary parameters:

```
await websocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://..."), CancellationToken.None);
await SendMessage(websocketClient, requestBody);
await ReceiveMessage(websocketClient);
```

Comment: If I comment out everything after the first while loop, and comment out the `await websocketClient.SendAsync()` line, the exception never gets thrown and the connection is made okay. As soon as I uncomment the SendAsync I get the exception at random again.

Comment: After some more testing, I can see that the shorter the value of 'delay' is, the greater the proportion of requests that generate the error. At 100ms it's almost all of them.

Comment: I've now pretty much completely changed the way the process is managed, including the threading. I can only conclude that it's something out of my control. Perhaps it's even something happening between my house and the data centre that neither I nor AWS can do anything about. It could be my internet connection (a fairly new 920 MB/s FTTP connection) but then I would think I'd see all sorts of other issues.

Anyway, my new method includes some retry logic so I can now do the load testing anyway. This morning it did a 1,000 requests okay! So it _is_ intermittent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: When setting up a websocket API on AWS, use mock endpoints for the connect and disconnect routes, *not* Lambda functions, to return the 200 response.**

Solved it. It seems the 'unable to connect' errors were a secondary consequence of how I'd set up the websocket API routes.

Having followed an article on this, I'd set up two Lambda functions that return a 200 response, that serve as the endpoints for the $connect and $disconnect websocket routes. These contain one line of Javascript that returns `{"statusCode":200}`.

What seems to have been happening is that when the 'connect' Lambda function was invoked it was returning a 'rate exceeded' error instead of a 200 response, which appears to the client as 'unable to connect'.

The solution: dispense with the Lambda functions altogether and use mock endpoints that pass through a template containing the 200 response instead.

So now I'm always able to connect because I don't need to invoke a Lambda function just to create a websocket connection. Instead, the 'rate exceeded' error occurs when the message is sent to invoke the function that does the actual data processing, and it's much more obvious what's going on.

Fundamentally, the problem seems to be that Lambda concurrency is only set to 10, despite the documentation stating that the default is 1,000. I'm now in a better position to evidence a request for an increase.